# Can individuals impose rules on the Chancel?

Tags: nobilis

Is it possible for a noble to exclude things from a certain area of Chancel?

I know that certain technology levels can be banned from Chancel, but Chancel is a shared space between players, and time periods of two nobles may not match.  For example someone is playing as the god of swords — as such he doesn't want guns in his area. But a Chancel is a shared space and someone is playing as the god of rifles, so guns being banned is not an option.

Can the god of swords say, "This area of Chancel is mine and I say guns don't work in this area."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Look to their Realm & Domain

You're looking for a hard rule here, and I don't think Nobilis is going to have a hard rule for that. This is gonna fall into the *Rulings, not Rules* category, as well as the *If the rules don't say you can't, then you can* category. If it seems possible for a god to do, then a Noble probably can do it. In other words, can you imagine a story in which a god-imbued mortal was able to protect a certain area of their magic faery kingdom from guns? If so, then probably yes, barring interference from other Nobles.

But even if there's not a hard rule, (they couldn't possibly anticipate everything you could do with god-level power, after all), there is a thought process for determining what people are capable of based on their Attributes.

### Domain Miracles (pg. 97, Nobilis 2e)

The character's Domain is Swords in your example. Therefore, they can do the following things with the concept of "Swords" (provided they are high enough level or have enough Miracle Points):

- Know about Swords (Lesser/Major Divinations)
- Preserve Swords (Lesser/Major Preservation)
- Change Swords (Lesser/Major Changes)
- Destroy Swords (Lesser/Major Destruction)
- Create Swords (Lesser/Major Creation)

The key here is the Destruction Miracle type. The Swords character is able to destroy swords, make swords not be able to cut, make swords be weightless, etc... via a Lesser or Major Destruction. However, the character has no authority over Guns. Ironically, it'd be easy for the character to make an area that was free of Swords than one free of Guns.

### Realm Miracles (pg, 97, Nobilis 2E)

> Realm is much more general than Domain, allowing one to affect anything

Hence, a Noble can perform any miracle within their Chancel, from any Domain. By my reckoning, your Swords Noble needs to have (or be able to reach through MP expenditure) Realm Level 5 ("Tempest") to ban Guns from an area in their home Chancel. This would allow them to do a Lesser Destruction of Guns within their home Chancel.

### Gifts

Also, be aware that you can build a Gift that uses a Domain outside of the Nobilis's Estate. Hence, although your Noble is "Swords", he could have a limited power in "Guns", e.g. the power to banish them.

Comment: As an alternative approach: what ability set would you need to make it so that Swords are able to parry bullets?

Comment: Had to take a step back and rethink Preservation. Preservation allows you to "ward" something, not "ward something off". Ergo, Destruction would be the way to get rid of Guns. The answer remains mostly the same.

Comment: @AlexP, whole new question, really. OP is asking how to prevent Guns from entering a segment of a Chancel, not how to defend from Guns. From context, with reference to the rules that banish technology from a Chancel, OP is trying to have a protected area in which guns cannot exist. But, you've hit on the core of Nobilis. It isn't about whether you can do something. It's about how you're going to do it.